# OpenTK Toolkit Sample Browser crashes

Tags: c#, opentk

Im trying to use OpenTK in a program of mine.

I tried the **GLControl Simple, under OpenTK samples**. But it doesn't work, and I don't have enough experience to find the solution. Can somebody help me?

This is the error I get:

[image: Error]

The error message states:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContextException: Context creation failed. Wgl.CreateContext() error: -1073283041.
   at OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinGLContext..ctor(GraphicsMode format, WinWindowInfo window, IGraphicsContext sharedContext, Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags) in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\Windows\WinGLContext.cs:line 185
   at OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinFactory.CreateGLContext(GraphicsMode mode, IWindowInfo window, IGraphicsContext shareContext, Boolean directRendering, Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags) in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Platform\Windows\WinFactory.cs:line 97
   at OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsContext..ctor(GraphicsMode mode, IWindowInfo window, Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags) in c:\temp\opentk\Source\OpenTK\Graphics\GraphicsContext.cs:line 151
   at OpenTK.WinGLControl.CreateContext(Int32 major, Int32 minor, GraphicsContextFlags flags)
   at OpenTK.GLControl.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5485 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Examples
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.1664.6217
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/exj508/Documents/OpenTK/1.1/Binaries/OpenTK/Release/Examples.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5491 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8686 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5495 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5483 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5494 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
OpenTK
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.1664.6217
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/exj508/Documents/OpenTK/1.1/Binaries/OpenTK/Release/OpenTK.DLL
----------------------------------------
OpenTK.GLControl
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.1664.6217
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/exj508/Documents/OpenTK/1.1/Binaries/OpenTK/Release/OpenTK.GLControl.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I have the following graphics card:

- **Card:** Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
- **Driver Version:** 10.18.10.3621

if you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the device driver from the website of Intel itself. The Microsoft provided ones are no good.

Comment: I installed the driver from the hp website, but I will search on the intel website for a newer one

Comment: Ok that was the problem, intel has newer drivers on his website

Comment: I thought so ;) I had a variation of this problem myself. Vendors do not update their drivers as regularly as the actual graphics card manufacturers.

Comment: Yea true, thx btw, I was actually searching for this awnser for 2 days xD